# Get two's complement for a byte

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation, xor, twos-complement

[Two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is when each bit in the byte is flipped and then a '1' is added to the result.

I don't want to extract each bit and flip it.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the byte to a negative value (after you convert it to integer):

```
b = CByte(-CSHort(b) And &HFF)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply XOR the byte with 255, then add one.

```
Dim myByte1 As Byte = 5
Dim myByte2 As Byte = 255
Dim MyTwosComplement As Byte

MyTwosComplement = myByte1 Xor myByte2
MyTwosComplement = CByte(MyTwosComplement + 1)
```

Comment: CByte in the last line will fix it with Option Strict. (edited answer)

Comment: I was hoping Killakeys would fix it... but anyway, that doesn't work for `myByte1 = 0`.

Comment: You're right. You can also use a negative operator -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other definition for two's complement: `2^n - b` where n is the number of bits.

```
Function TwosComplement(b As Byte) As Byte
    Return CByte((256 - b) And &HFF)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 Dim b as Byte = 5
 Dim twosCompliment As Byte = (Not b) + 1
```

Comment: This doesn't compile with Option Strict On, and it doesn't work when `b = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

...

Public Function TwosComplement(value As Byte) As Byte
    If value = 0 Then Return 0 Else Return CByte(CByte(value Xor Byte.MaxValue) + 1)
End Function
```